# ReferenceError: document is not defined at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript

I am following a youtube tutorial the guy in the tutorial is able to execute the code in the browser but i am unable to do the same.
The following is the error that pops up in the terminal.

````
C:\vs projects\booklistapp\bookapp.js:47
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded
', UI.displayBooks);
^



ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\vs projects\b
ooklistapp\bookapp.js:47:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cj
s/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (inter
nal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/lo
ader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/
loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modu
les/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/mo
dules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:
283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootst
rap/node.js:622:3)```
````

Comment: `at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3` indicates that you try to run the script using nodejs. And the stack trace doe snot indicated that you use any module that tries to emulate a browser environment that would provide `document`. And `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayBooks);` is clearly a code that belongs in a browser environment (or in the ui part of e.g. electron - which is actually a browser).

Answer (score 2):

You are running in Node.js, which does not have a window or document.
If you want to run it in a browser, add the script tag to an html file and run the html file in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Hello from the browser</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="C:\vs projects\booklistapp\bookapp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.I had forgotten to add the script tag.